# Push to Heroku gives PG password error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to push my local PG database to Heroku using taps (heroku db:push). I have done this before with no issue, but today Heroku isn't accepting my push. Here is there error:

```
funkdified@funkpad:~/rails_projects/goodtb$ heroku db:push postgres://goodtb@127.0.0.1/goodtb_development?encoding=utf8 --confirm goodtb
Loaded Taps v0.3.24
Warning: Data in the app 'goodtb' will be overwritten and will not be recoverable.
Failed to connect to database:
  Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError -> PG::Error: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

I have no password for development or production in my database.yml file.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

For some reason not having a password on the development pg server was unacceptable to complete the heroku db:push. I'm not sure maybe this changed with the new heroku toolbelt.

So, basically I changed "trust" to "md5" in the pg-hba.conf file, then went into the postgres admin tool in the console to perform the ALTER USER and add a password. Once this was complete I was able to perform:

```
heroku db:push postgres://goodtb:password@127.0.0.1/goodtb_development?encoding=utf8 --confirm goodtb
```